# Ping-Pong на Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing, awt

Доброго времени суток. Пример из книги, символ в символ, но не работает, шарик не перемещается. В чем причина? Исправлял на что ругается IDE, гуглил - всё бестолку.

```java
    package screens;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import engine.PingPongGameEngine;

/**
 Этот класс рисует стол для пинг-понга и отображает координаты
 точки,где пользователь кликнул мышью
 */

    public class PingPongGreenTable extends  JPanel
implements  GameConstants{

      private  JLabel label;
      private int computerRacket_Y=COMPUTER_RACKET_Y_START;
      private int kidRacket_Y=KID_RACKET_Y_START;
      private int ballX= BALL_START_X;
      private int ballY = BALL_START_Y;


    private Dimension preferredSize= new Dimension(TABLE_WIDTH,TABLE_HEIGHT);

    // Устанавливаем размеры окна.Вызывается виртуальной машиной

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return preferredSize;
    }

    //Конструктор. Создает обработчик событий мыши.
    public PingPongGreenTable(){
        PingPongGameEngine gameEngine = new PingPongGameEngine(this);

        // Обрабатываем движения мыши для передвижения ракеток
        addMouseMotionListener (gameEngine);

        // Обрабатываем  события клавиатуры
        addKeyListener(gameEngine);
    }

// Добавить панель с JLabel в окно
 void addPaneltoFrame(Container container) {
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container,
                BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        container.add(this);

        label=new JLabel("Press N for a new game, S to serve or Q to quit");
        container.add(label);
    }
    // Перерисовать окно. Этот метод вызывается виртуальной
    // машиной, когда нужно обновить экран или
    // вызывается метод repaint() из PingPointGameEngine

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Нарисовать зеленый стол
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0,0,TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT);

        // Нарисовать правую ракетку
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(KID_RACKET_X, kidRacket_Y,RACKET_WIDTH, RACKET_LENGTH);


        // Нарисовать левую ракетку
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(COMPUTER_RACKET_X, computerRacket_Y,
                RACKET_WIDTH, RACKET_LENGTH);

        // Нарисовать мяч
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(ballX,ballY,10,10);

        // Нарисовать белые линии
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(10,10,300,200);
        g.drawLine(160,10,160,210);

// Установить фокус на стол, чтобы
// обработчик клавиатуры мог посылать команды столу
        requestFocus();

        }



    // Установить текущее положение ракетки ребенка
    public void setKidRacket_Y(int yCoordinate) {
        this.kidRacket_Y=yCoordinate;
        repaint();
    }

    // Вернуть текущее положение ракетки ребенка
    public int getKidRacket_Y(){

        return kidRacket_Y;
    }

    // Установить текущее положение ракетки компьютера

    public void setComputerRacket_Y(int yCoordinate){

        this.computerRacket_Y= yCoordinate;
        repaint();
    }

    // Установить игровое сообщение
    public void setMessageText(String text){
        label.setText(text);
        repaint();
    }
    // Установить позицию мяча
    public void setBallPosition (int xPos, int yPos){
        ballX=xPos;
        ballY=yPos;
        repaint();

    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        // Создать экземпляр окна
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Ping Pong Green Table");

        // Убедиться, что окно может быть закрыто по нажатию на
       //крестик в углу
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation (WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        PingPongGreenTable table = new PingPongGreenTable();
        table.addPaneltoFrame(f.getContentPane());

        // Установить размер окна и сделать его видимым
        f.setBounds(0,0,TABLE_WIDTH+5, TABLE_HEIGHT+40);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

```java
    package engine;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import screens.*;

public class PingPongGameEngine implements Runnable,
                MouseMotionListener, KeyListener, GameConstants {

    private PingPongGreenTable table; // ссылка на стол
    private int kidRacket_Y = KID_RACKET_Y_START;
    private int computerRacket_Y = COMPUTER_RACKET_Y_START;
    private int kidScore;
    private int computerScore;
    private int ballX; // координата X мяча
    private int ballY; // координата Y мяча
    private boolean movingLeft = true;
    private boolean ballServed = false;

    //Значение вертикального передвижения мяча в пикселях
    private int verticalSlide;

    // Конструктор. Содержит ссылку на объект стола

    public PingPongGameEngine(PingPongGreenTable greenTable) {
        table = greenTable;

        Thread worker = new Thread(this);
        worker.start();
    }
    // Обязательные методы из интерфейса MouseListener
    // (некоторые из них пустые,но должны быть включены все равно)

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        int mouse_Y = e.getY();

        // Если мышь находится выше ракетки ребенка
        // и не выходит за пределы стола – передвинуть ее вверх,
        // в противном случае – опустить вниз

        if (mouse_Y < kidRacket_Y && kidRacket_Y > TABLE_TOP) {

            kidRacket_Y -= RACKET_INCREMENT;

        }else if(kidRacket_Y < TABLE_BOTTOM) {
                kidRacket_Y += RACKET_INCREMENT;
            }

            // Установить новое положение ракетки
            table.setKidRacket_Y(kidRacket_Y);
        }

        // Обязательные методы из интерфейса KeyListener
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){

            char key = e.getKeyChar();

            if ('n' == key || 'N' == key) {
                startNewGame();
            } else if('q' == key || 'Q' == key) {
                endGame();
            } else if('s' == key || 'S' == key) {
                kidServe();
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e){}

        public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e){}

        // Начать новую игру
        private void startNewGame() {

            computerScore = 0;
            kidScore = 0;
            table.setMessageText("Score Computer: 0 Kid:0");

            kidServe();
        }

        // Завершить игру
        private void endGame() {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Обязательный метод run() из интерфейса Runnable
        public void run () {
            boolean canBounce = false;

            while (true) {

               if(ballServed) { //если мяч движется

                    //Шаг 1. Мяч движется влево?
                    if (movingLeft && ballX > BALL_MIN_X) {

                        canBounce = (ballY >= computerRacket_Y &&
                                ballY < (computerRacket_Y + RACKET_LENGTH)?true:false);

                        ballX -= BALL_INCREMENT;

                        // Добавить смещение вверх или вниз к любым
                        // движениям мяча влево или вправо
                        ballY -= verticalSlide;

                        table.setBallPosition(ballX, ballY);

                        // Может отскочить?
                        if (ballX <= COMPUTER_RACKET_X && canBounce) {
                            movingLeft = false;
                        }
                    }

                    // Шаг 2. Мяч движется вправо?
                    if ( !movingLeft && ballX <= BALL_MAX_X) {
                        canBounce = (ballY >= kidRacket_Y && ballY <
                                (kidRacket_Y + RACKET_LENGTH)?true:false);

                        ballX += BALL_INCREMENT;
                        table.setBallPosition(ballX, ballY);

                        // Может отскочить?

                        if (ballX >= KID_RACKET_X && canBounce) {
                            movingLeft = true;
                        }
                    }
                    // Шаг 3. Перемещать ракетку компьютера вверх или вниз,
                    // чтобы блокировать мяч
                    if (computerRacket_Y < ballY
                            && computerRacket_Y < TABLE_BOTTOM) {

                        computerRacket_Y += RACKET_INCREMENT;

                    } else if (computerRacket_Y > TABLE_TOP) {
                        computerRacket_Y -= RACKET_INCREMENT;
                    }
                    table.setComputerRacket_Y(computerRacket_Y);

                    // Шаг 4. Приостановить

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Шаг 5. Обновить счет, если мяч зеленой области, но не движется

                    if (isBallOnTheTable()) {
                        if (ballX > BALL_MAX_X) {

                            computerScore++;
                            displayScore();

                        } else if (ballX < BALL_MIN_X) {
                            kidScore++;
                            displayScore();

                        }
                    }

                } // Конец if ballServed
            } // Конец while
        }// Конец run()


        // Подать с текущей позиции ракетки ребенка

        private void kidServe () {

            ballServed = true;
            ballX = KID_RACKET_X - 1;
            ballY = kidRacket_Y;

            if (ballY > TABLE_HEIGHT / 2) {

                verticalSlide = -1;

            } else {
                verticalSlide = 1;
            }
            table.setBallPosition(ballX, ballY);
            table.setKidRacket_Y(kidRacket_Y);
        }

        private void displayScore () {

            ballServed = false;

            if (computerScore == WINNING_SCORE) {
                table.setMessageText("Computer won!" + computerScore +
                        ":" + kidScore);
            } else if (kidScore == WINNING_SCORE) {
                table.setMessageText("You won" + kidScore +
                        ":" + computerScore);
            } else {
                table.setMessageText("Computer:" + computerScore +
                        "Kid:" + kidScore);

            }
        }

        // Проверить, не пересек ли мяч верхнюю или нижнюю границу стола

        private boolean isBallOnTheTable () {
            if (ballY >= BALL_MIN_Y && ballY <= BALL_MAX_Y) {

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
package screens;
public interface GameConstants {
    public final int TABLE_WIDTH = 320;
    public final int TABLE_HEIGHT = 220;
    public final int TABLE_TOP = 12;
    public final int TABLE_BOTTOM = 180;

    // Шаг перемещения мяча в пикселях
    public final int BALL_INCREMENT = 4;

    // Максимальные и минимальные координаты мяча
    public final int BALL_MIN_X = 1+ BALL_INCREMENT;
    public final int BALL_MIN_Y = 1 + BALL_INCREMENT;
    public final int BALL_MAX_X = TABLE_WIDTH - BALL_INCREMENT;
    public final int BALL_MAX_Y = TABLE_HEIGHT - BALL_INCREMENT;

    // Начальные координаты мяча
    public final int BALL_START_X = TABLE_WIDTH/2;
    public final int BALL_START_Y = TABLE_HEIGHT/2;

    //Размеры, расположения и шаг перемещения ракеток
    public final int KID_RACKET_X = 300;
    public final int KID_RACKET_Y_START = 100;
    public final int COMPUTER_RACKET_X = 15;
    public final int COMPUTER_RACKET_Y_START = 100;
    public final int RACKET_INCREMENT = 2;
    public final int RACKET_LENGTH = 30;
    public final int RACKET_WIDTH = 5;
    public final int WINNING_SCORE = 21;

    // Замедлить быстрые компьютеры – измените это значение,
// если понадобится

    public final int SLEEP_TIME = 10; //время в миллисекундах
}
```

Comment: Вы создаёте объект потока в конструкторе, запускаете его и он тут же умирает, или я запамятовал и из метода старт мы не выходим?

Comment: Посмотрел доку и да, объект потока умирает сразу же.  Сделайте ваш worker полем класса/объекта

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а можете, пожалуйста, другими словами сказать. Не понимаю

Comment: В конструкторе PingPongGameEngine вы создаете локальную переменную worker и она тут же удаляется

Comment: @Alexander Chernin спасибо, я всё понял)

Comment: Переменная удаляется, а поток не должен. Если поток исчезает, то думаю, у него exception в потоке, который не перехватывается и поток умирает.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin "Посмотрел доку и да, объект потока умирает сразу же" - ну чепуха же.

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov не сразу? Из старта же выходим и все, объект удаляется, или что?

Comment: Поток завершается, когда завершается его метод run(). Объект потока удаляется, когда поток завершился и нет ссылок. Для проверки можешь запустить  поток, не сохраняя ссылки на него, в цикле писать в system.out и убедишься, что в консоль будет сыпаться бесконечно.

Answer (score 0):

Что за книга такая славная?

Тут классический пример отсутствия синхронизации между потоками. Весь UI крутится в одном потоке и обработка событий игры в другом (worker в твоём коде).

Когда в ты нажимаешь N, вызывается `startNewGame() -> kidServe() -> ballServed=true;`, но другой поток не видит изменения переменной `ballServed`, потому что он на уровне процессора закэшировал значение `ballServed=false`.

Чтобы заставить процессор перечитывать значение переменной каждый раз, тебе надо объявить все переменные как `volatile`, например `private volatile boolean ballServed`.

Игра начнёт шевелиться, но работать правильно возможно не будет, потому что синхронизации между потоками всё ещё нет. Мне неохота весь код вычитывать, если какие-то переменные пишутся из обоих потоков, то это надо синхронизировать.

Я ещё AWT/Swing не очень хорошу помню - разве там можно из любого потока UI обновлять? см. https://dzone.com/articles/multi-threading-java-swing

Comment: Такая вот книга: YakovFayn - Java Programming for Kids Parents and Grandparents

Comment: Вроде не такая старая книга. Могу только предположить, что автор тестировал всё на однопроцессорном компьютере.